# using R & paws how switch/assume different IAM Role?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, r-paws

I'm logging in successfully to AWS via paws however am in the parent account.

```
library(paws)

Sys.setenv(
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "*****************************************",
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "************************************",
  AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = "******************************************************************",
  AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
)

mys3<- paws::s3()
temp_s3 <- mys3$list_buckets()
```

I'm want to change to a child account and list the buckets under it.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by “child” and “parent” accounts? Could you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Logged in from the console this would click on your user account -> switch role -> and then specify a new account # and role.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Switching Role via API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html).

Provided that you have all the necessary rights and parameters, you should use the methods of the STS service, Paws seems to cover all the basic ones and you can find their [documentation here](https://paws-r.github.io/docs/sts/).